# Showing that an Element of PID is Finite Product of Irreducible Elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification

1. Let $R$ be a Principal Ideal Domain.
2. Let $0 \ne a \in R$ be a non-unit.
3. Suppose for sake of contradiction that $a$ weren't a finite product of irreducible elements.
4. Then $a = bc = (de)c = \ldots$ would be possible s.t. $b,c,d,e \in R$ were reducible non-units of $R$.
5. Then $(a) \subsetneq (b) \subsetneq (d) \ldots$ must stop at some point since $R$ is a Principal Ideal Domain.
6. Then $a$ is a product a finite number of irreducible elements as desired.

**Question:** Why is the ascending chain in (5) necessarily a **proper** ascending chain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key issue is that, for example, if $(a)=(b)$, then $a=ub$ for some unit $u$. This isn't too hard to prove: $a=bx$ and $b=ay$ implies that $a=bx=ayx$, and cancelling $a$ we have $1=xy$, so that $x,y$ are units.

In $4$ you posited that $a=bc$ for some *nonunits* $b,c$. If $a=bc=bu$, then this implies $c=u$ is a unit, which is a contradiction.

Similarly, no links in the chain can be equal, or else you are contradiction the assumption made in point $4$.